# Trying to override and extend method signature in child class in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance

I have a base class that I am trying to extend:

```
export class BaseClass<T extends SomeOtherClass> {
  constructor(param: ParamType) {
  }

  doSomething(param1: Param1Type): BaseClass<T> {
    // do something with param1;
    return this;
  } 
}
```

My class:

```
export class MyClass<T extends SomeOtherClass> extends BaseClass<T> {

  constructor(param: ParamType) {
    super(param);
  }

  doSomething(param1: Param1Type, param2: Param2Type): MyClass<T> {
    // super.doSomething(param1);
    // do something with param2;
    return this;
  }
}
```

but I'm getting a warning:

```
Property 'doSomething' in type 'MyClass<T>' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'BaseClass<T>'.
  Type '(param1: Param1Type, param2: Param2Type) => MyClass<T>' is not assignable to type '(param1: Param1Type) => BaseClass<T>'.
```

Is it not possible to extend method signatures in typescript? How do I extend the capabilities of the BaseClass if I need to add a parameter to the overridden method and is this the correct way of calling the parent method in es6 syntax. I'm aware that prior to es6 I could have called BaseClass.prototype.doSomething.call(this, param1).

Comment: It seems like this would work if you change `MyClass`'s method to be called `doSomethingElse`. You could even still call `super.doSomething(param1)`.

Comment: that would also work. I think the other issues is that the original methods are returning a reference to "this" .In typescript the type of the returned this is ParentClass which is not the same shape as ChildClass. So some methods of the child class will return a ParentClass "this" while the overridden methods will return a ChildClass "this". Both will actually return the same object but typescript doesn't seem to like it because it seems them as different types.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem as pointed out by others is that if `param2` is required it breaks polymorphism:

```
// We should be able to do this assignment 
let baseRef: BaseClass<SomeOtherClass> = new MyClass<SomeOtherClass>(""); 
baseRef.doSomething("") // param2 is not required by the base class so MyClass will not receive it even though it NEEDS it
```

One solution, is to make the second parameter optional, so the call `baseRef.doSomething("")` is valid for the derived type as well :

```
export class MyClass<T extends SomeOtherClass> extends BaseClass<T> {

    constructor(param: string) {
        super(param);
    }

    doSomething(param1: string, param2?: string): MyClass<T> {
        super.doSomething(param1);
        return this;
    }
}
```

A second solution, if we only want to share code between the classes, is to disallow the assignment `let baseRef: BaseClass<SomeOtherClass> = new MyClass<SomeOtherClass>("");` by not really inheriting `BaseClass` but rather inherit a class that excludes the `doSomething` method:

```
type PartialBaseClass = new <T> (param: string)  => { [P in Exclude<keyof BaseClass<T>, 'doSomething'>] : BaseClass<T>[P] }
const PartialBaseClass:PartialBaseClass = BaseClass

export class MyClass<T extends SomeOtherClass> extends PartialBaseClass<T> {

    constructor(param: string) {
        super(param);
    }

    doSomething(param1: string, param2: string): MyClass<T> {
        BaseClass.prototype.doSomething.call(this, param1);
        return this;
    }
}
// This is now invalid ! 
let baseRef: BaseClass<SomeOtherClass> = new MyClass<SomeOtherClass>("")    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a violation of OOP as it would break polymorphism. An example where you might typically use this could be with a base class Filter and a derived class FilterWithDelay. The parent class implements a method called setFilter. In OOP you might have an array of Filters which contains instances of both Filter and FilterWithDelay. You might typically want to iterate through the array and call setFilter on each object. For this to be possible the child method should implement the same function signature as the parent method. Otherwise the code, would need to check each instance to see if its a Filter or FilterWithDelay in order to pass in the additional parameters.

In order to implement the FilterWithDelay you can extend the parent class and pass the delay as a parameter to the constructor instead of the method. This way setFilter can implement the common interface.

```
export class BaseClass<T extends SomeOtherClass> {
  constructor(param: ParamType) {
  }

  doSomething(param1: Param1Type): BaseClass<T> {
    // do something with param1;
    return this;
  } 
}

export class MyClass<T extends SomeOtherClass> extends BaseClass<T> {

  constructor(param: ParamType, param2: Param2Type) {
    super(param);
    this.param2 = param2;
  }

  doSomething(param1: Param1Type): MyClass<T> {
    return super.doSomething(param1 + this.param2);
  }
}
```